# How to display the JSON data in a html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

Here I am fetching the JSON data from the API using an AJAX call. And I need to display the data in a html format. Can anyone tell me how to do to that? My JSON data looks like this:

```
"vjginteractive":{"signup_date_time":"2017-04-11 01:34:19","package_id":"2","total_leads":0},"vmlsingapore":{"signup_date_time":"2016-05-31 07:33:38","package_id":"2","total_leads":"not_available"},"vodkafashionindia":{"signup_date_time":"2016-03-17 18:15:48","package_id":"2","total_leads":0}
```

This what I have tried. How to display the Company name, Visits and Leads in a table format?

```js
$(document).ready(function()
  {
var X = [];
var Y = [];
var data = [];
function loadJSON(callback) {
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/nihnp', true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
            callback(xobj.responseText);
        }
    }
    xobj.send(null);
}
loadJSON(function(response) {
    var response;
    var field=JSON.parse(response);
    var values=[];
    for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
        var $this=field[i];
        for (var key in $this) {
          if ($this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var val = $this[key];
            values.push({"x":val.total_visits,"y":val.total_leads});
          }
        }
    }
});
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 560px; width: 100%;"></div>
</head>
```

Comment: You can use something like JQuery Data table....https://datatables.net/

Comment: I would suggest to use latest jQuery 3.2.1 (1.11.1 is not supported anymore)

Answer (score 3):

You can get `Object`'s keys with `Object.keys` that will return you an `Array` with all the keys. Then you can just use `forEach` to iterate over them.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function loadJSON(callback) {
    const data = '{"vjginteractive":{"signup_date_time":"2017-04-11 01:34:19","package_id":"2","total_leads":0},"vmlsingapore":{"signup_date_time":"2016-05-31 07:33:38","package_id":"2","total_leads":"not_available"},"vodkafashionindia":{"signup_date_time":"2016-03-17 18:15:48","package_id":"2","total_leads":0}}';
    callback(JSON.parse(data));
  }

  loadJSON(function(response) {
    const $table = $('#chartContainer');
    Object.keys(response)
      .forEach((key) => {
        const field = response[key];
        $table.append(
          `<tr>
          <td>${field.signup_date_time}</td>
          <td>${field.package_id}</td>
          <td>${field.total_leads}</td>
          </tr>`);
      });
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table id="chartContainer"></table>
</head>
```